# If series data array is null show message no data available

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am using highcharts with angularjs (highcharts-ng) and getting series data dynamically that series data array may be null, if null I want to display message some thing like "No data available" in graph div.
How can I do this??

Comment: Have you tried to use `no-data-to-display.js` plugin? See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#noData).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a div before your chart that appears only if no data is null like;

```
<div ng-if="myData === null || (myData && myData.length === 0)">
     <h3>No data available</h3>
</div>
```